# CAPTCHA checking fail no matter i input correctly

Tags: php, captcha

I am using secureImage which is a simple way to implement captcha,
i follow the guideline there to add the code, however, the checking is always invalid even i have input the correct value

It is the [website](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/) of that plugin, within ten lines of code:

And this is my code:

**in html form**

```
<img id="captcha" src="http://www.phpcaptcha.org/securimage3/securimage_show.php?0.6905195268336684" alt="CAPTCHA Image">

<input type="text" class="required" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6">
```

**in verification php**

```
include_once '../plugin/securimage/securimage.php';

$securimage = new Securimage();


if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
  die ("<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>The security code entered was incorrect.</strong><br /><br />Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.</div>");
}
```

I have checked the post value, that is exactly what i have inputted. I would like to know which data the plugin used to compare with my input, however, i can not do this by echo the $secureimage

Thank you

Comment: Don't use captchas. They exist merely to annoy users and to suit lazy administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the randomly generated image with the code entered by a user a valid session is required. Please check this [quick start guide](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/) and read the section about putting **session_start()** on top of your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are too lazy to code, maybe you can try at http://www.google.com/recaptcha. It's widely used, I think it is better than the secureimage. You can get a php implementation at [this site](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php). I am if sorry if I don't answer your questions directly, this was because mr.GolezTrol suggested to not to use it.